# Is there a way to convert a bytes slice to a custom type of a byte array

Tags: go

Say I have a some code like this:

```
type SomeType [16]byte

func foo(bar []byte) {
  ...
}
```

How can I copy `bar` in `foo()` to a `SomeType` instance?

Comment: Yes. I'll close it.

Answer (score 4):

As of Go 1.17 you can [convert a slice to an array pointer](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_from_slice_to_array_pointer) so long as the slice is at least large enough to fill the declared array. This would only meet your needs if you expect bar to be at least 16 bytes.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeType [16]byte

func foo(bar []byte) SomeType {
    return *(*SomeType)(bar)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo([]byte("A 16 byte slice!")))                   // works
    fmt.Println(foo([]byte("A 16 byte slice and then some more"))) // works but you only access the first 16 bytes
    fmt.Println(foo([]byte("too short")))                          // panics because the underlying array is too short
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `copy`, but convert the array to a slice first:

```
type SomeType [16]byte

func foo(bar []byte) SomeType {
    var ret SomeType
    copy(ret[:], bar)
    return ret
}

func main() {
    r := foo([]byte{1, 2, 3})
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```